# Linker doesn't notify multiple definitions

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I have two files `foo.c` and `foo2.c` which are exactly the same. If I link to both of them then the linker will throw an error complaining about multiple function definitions.

But if I first compile one file into static library and link to the other object file and the library, then the linking process completes normally. I am using gcc 5.4.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.

**foo.c** and **foo2.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fooxyz(void) {
    printf("foo\n");
}
```

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fooxyz(void);

int main(void) {
    fooxyz();
    return 1;
}
```

Now compile and archive foo2 into libfoo2.a:

```
$ gcc -c main.c foo.c foo2.c
$ ar rcs libfoo2.a foo2.o
$ gcc -o main main.o foo.o -L. -lfoo2
$ ./main
foo
```

Why doesn't the linker throw an error about the multiple definition of function `fooxyz` since it is defined in two places? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if I first compile one file into static library and link to the other object file and the library, then the linking process completes normally. I am using gcc 5.4.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.

That's expected.

A symbol from the library is used only if it is not defined in any of the object files being linked.

Comment: So I guess this is the reason libraries are put behind the object files in linker command.

Comment: @radiohead: Yes; that is one of the reasons why libraries should follow object files on the command line.  You could experiment with two different versions of `fooxyz()` — say by using `printf("%s:%s()\n", __FILE__, __func__);` to print the file name.  Then see which function is linked.  Try altering the library, replacing the object files in different sequences, and see what you get.  The result is indeterminate, though.  That is, no specification says which of two implementations of the same function name in a single library will actually be picked up. So, the double definition is a problem!

Comment: @radiohead, You can use libraries ahead of the object files in the linker command. The behavior will be exactly the same. It is just a good habit.

Comment: @RSahu: It depends on the system, and the type of library.  With static libraries, most linkers won't rescan libraries if the first reference to a function is in an object file listed after the library that defines it.  It is *far* better to list libraries after object files.  You have to be really confident you know what you're doing to do otherwise.  What may work on one system will not necessarily work on others.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, thanks for the additional info. I have been stuck in MS world for far too long.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Agreed. Just tried `gcc -o main main.o -L. -lfoo2 foo.o`, and this time the linker throws multiple definition error. I found some useful info in this page explaining this behavior: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking.